# Auto Size cell based on UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextview

I have a UITextView in a UITableViewCell in the storyboard. I then added a constraint on all 4 sides of the UITextView.

In the code below I tried making the textView dynamically change as the user enters text. I'm pretty sure that worked successfully. But the problem is the cell is not. Bellow is the code I tried, without success.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44;
}

- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    if (textView == myTextView)
    {
        [self textViewFitToContent:myTextView];

        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:1 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
    }
    return YES;
}

- (void)textViewFitToContent:(UITextView *)textView
{
    CGFloat fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width;
    CGSize newSize = [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, MAXFLOAT)];
    CGRect newFrame = textView.frame;
    newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(fmaxf(newSize.width, fixedWidth), newSize.height);
    textView.frame = newFrame;
    textView.scrollEnabled = NO;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    return myTextView.frame.size.height + 40;
}
```

I'm a beginner so please don't be too harsh on me.

Thanks

Comment: All cells change height when only one is supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, flawless infact and quite well done. Without seeing your declared variables, I believe the reason that the cell isn't resizing is because you're `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method is returning the height of the wrong `UITextView`. Instead of `txtSymptoms` which isn't used anywhere else in the resizing code, you should be using `myTextView` instead, which, when the user edits the text of, will trigger the `tableView` to reload.

Comment: It was my bad. I thought I changed all the textViews name in stack overflow. I guess I forgot that one. But I don't think thats the problem

Comment: All textViews resize itself. which is wierd

Answer (score 0):

This snippet of yours:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return myTextView.frame.size.height + 40;
}
```

From the rest of your code, `myTextView` seems to be a special text view that you are adding text to and resizing, but this method uses that larger height for sizing, which is why *all* of your cells grow taller.

Comment: Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: If you are using iOS8's auto-sizing cells, then you don't need this method at all, an make sure that the preferred width is set to automatic in the storyboard for the label.

Comment: I just took it away and when I make a new line, the textView resizes itself correctly for a split second, then goes back to what it was set before. I think its because the cell height is not changing and i used auto constraint

Answer (score -1):

In the storyboard, select your text view and in the size inspector look for the content hugging priority option. 
Content hugging priority can range from 0 to 1000.

Keep the content hugging priority of your text view (for vertical section especially) higher than the content hugging priority of the content view of the cell in which the text view resides.

Comment: I don't quite understand